# Performance/time joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three data tables that have the same length (~50000), different columns (<500 each), and share a common "id" column.

They look like:

table A

```
   id    A1    A2   ...      
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ...  
   n    xxx   xxx   ...
```

table B

```
   id    B1    B2   ...  
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ... 
   n    xxx   xxx   ...
```

table C

```
   id    C1    C2   ...  
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ... 
   n    xxx   xxx   ...
```

I was trying to join them together using

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_C
ON table_A.id = table_C.id;
```

and it's been taking hours.

However, when I do it by two separate steps like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_0
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id;

CREATE TABLE my_table_1
SELECT *
FROM my_table_0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_C
ON my_table_0.id = table_C.id;
```

Each "step" only takes less than 5 minutes.

Does anyone know whether this is normal and what's causing it? I wonder if there is a faster way I can join three tables altogether without creating intermediary tables.

Comment: Perhaps MySQL struggles with producing a resultset with 1500 columns.  Do you really need that many columns in the output?  What kind of data is it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (My)SQL can be strange.

What maybe already could help in your case is using an inner join, if i understand this correctly all tables share the id column so this should be already a bit faster.

To get a better understanding about what is going on when you execute your query you can use the `EXPLAIN` keyword, there are some articles using it and understanding the output.

For example this is a good read: https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 0):

When doing a UNION of 2 tables, you should use `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Would you try to execute below codes and let me know if it works:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
FULL OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id
FULL OUTER JOIN table_C
ON table_A.id = table_C.id;
```

And if you would like to join the 3 tables while maintaining the length of the first table (same number of rows), you should use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id
LEFT JOIN table_C
ON table_A.id = table_C.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SQL software, not all would understand `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Try to use either `OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`.